# Control key is not getting detected

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener, key-events

This key event is not working.  The same code is working for,

```
VK_SPACE
```

Its not working for control

```
private void jTextArea1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if ((evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)) {
        System.out.println("CONTROL IS PRESSED");
    }
}
```

Comment: CTRL is a modifier key. I guess it doesn't fire the keyPressed event.

Comment: As mKorbel as pointed out, `KeyListeners` are not your best friend.  In you case (and without knowing more), I'd be suggesting the use of [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [`getKeyChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29) in combination with those `VK_` constants. Use [`getKeyCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29) instead. `getKeyChar` is for printable keys only, which result in a character being printed in normal operations. `getKeyCode`, on the other hand, is intended to give you the code (i.e. the `VK_` constant) of the key pressed, even if there is no associated character (as in the case of Ctrl).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381679/1468366).

Comment: wrong direction, there are `Document`, `DocumentXxx` and `TextAction`

Answer (score 3):

There is a method on the `java.awt.event.KeyEvent` just for your purpose - [`isControlDown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isControlDown%28%29)

Comment: checked, single Ctrl is getting detected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- there no reason to use `KeyListener` or `KeyBindings` or `AWTEventDispatch`
- use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for event to outside from `JTextCompoent`
- use [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) for filtering inside [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html)

Comment: It very much depends on what you're trying to do. E.g. the core of the example in the question, performing some action the moment Ctrl is pressed, isn't available through these interfaces. And there *might* be reasons to do such a thing.

Comment: @MvG I miss reason, doesn't make me sence listening for SHIFT or CTRL is pressed, because JTextComponents aren't designated for that, but nobody know real idea ..., out of upvotes ...